# logarithm of a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I have a task to study a function like this one:

$$F(z) = \frac{\ln(e^{iz^4})}{z^3}$$

I'm trying to simplify this: since the exponential is the inverse function of $\ln()$ can we simplify it to be:

$$iz$$?

**Edit:** I know from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) that :
$$\log(z) =  ln(r) + i\theta$$

But my problem is with :
$\ln(e^{iz}) = \ln(e^{ix-y})$ can we simplify it to: $ ix-y$ ?

Comment: $$\ln e^u =u$$, right?

Comment: You have $\exp(\ln u)=u$, but, since $\exp$ is not injective, not necessarily $\ln(\exp u)=u$. So you have to ask yourself which $\ln$ you are using and where your function is defined.

Comment: @lab is this also correct when u contains an imaginary number?

Comment: @Mike then is it possible to reduce $F(z)$ into a form : $x +iy$

Comment: @user689, I meant $\ln (u)$ as the principal value of  Log$(u)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value)

Comment: @lab: It is not correct for the princal value: $\ln(\exp(3\pi i)) = \pi i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $z \mapsto iz^4$ is one branch of $\ln e^{iz^4}$. All branches of $\ln e^{iz^4}$ are therefore

$$f_k(z) = iz^4 + 2\pi ik,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

The possible branches of $F$ are hence

$$F_k(z) = iz + \frac{2\pi ik}{z^3},\quad k \in\mathbb{Z}.$$

$F_0(z) = iz$ is the only entire branch, all others have a pole (of order $3$) in $0$.

> But my problem is with : $\ln(e^{iz})=\ln(e^{ix−y})$ can we simplify it to: $ix−y$ ?

If you are free to choose the branch of the logarithm, you can choose that branch. Otherwise, either list all possible branches, $ix - y + 2\pi ik,\; k\in\mathbb{Z}$, or if a specific branch is prescribed, use that.

Comment: Nice and simple explanation! Thanks.